# jQuery .on() not working with long dynamic content on Android and css()

Tags: android, jquery, event-delegation

I'm trying to bind interactions to dynamically loaded links:

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    My dynamic content will be here.
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    loadContent();
    $('#content').css('height',400);


    $('#content').on('click','a',function(){
        alert();
    });
});
```

This is working fine on desktop, and with a quite short content on Android.

But it will not work with longer content on Android (with no JS error on Eclipse). Yet, I have not identified any other differences but content length between working and not working pages. Therefore, I tried to artificially limit the length of the content, and then it is working fine.

Do you have any clues of what is happening ?

// EDIT

I updated the code as I had made some basic mistakes when typing this question. This version better reflects the core problem.

// EDIT

I finally managed to isolate what produced a conflict. It is due to a css update of the div after content being loaded. If I artificially remove the height style attribute using Weinre, then the links are clickable again!

Comment: You shouldn't need to, but put the click event handler assignment code inside the document.ready block, after `loadContent()`

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how this is working on desktop at all because the `on()` call should be inside the DOM ready handler, and the event name should come before the filtering element, like this:

```
$(function(){
    loadContent();

    $('#content').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        alert('something');    
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Those were typos that I fixed in the question. But it's not working better.

Comment: By the way, I also tried to bind the click action after content was loaded, using a deferred object. But it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

First, fix your document ready function to wrap `loadContent` and `on`.

Second, If you load content after the page is loaded. you should bind event to the `body` like this

```
$(function(){

    loadContent();

    $('body').on('click', '#content a', function(){
        alert('Hello world!');
    });

});
```